# TLS 1.2 .net 4.6.2 project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tls1.2

In the Appliction_Start method of Global.asax (MVC5 project) I have this line of code that should use TLS1.2

```
    if (ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol.HasFlag(SecurityProtocolType.Tls12) == false)
            {
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            }
```

inspecting the value of

`ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol`

at runtime shows this value

`System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12`

So Im assuming that TLS1.2 is being used, but Firefox shows this message in the console window

> 'This site uses a deprecated version of TLS that will be disabled in
>   March 2020. Please upgrade to TLS 1.2 or 1.3'

How can I ensure that TLS 1.2 is used ?  Im using the .net framework 4.6.2

Answer (score 1):

On this line:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

You're *adding* `Tls12` to the supported protocols. During handshake one of these supported protocols is selected depending on the client's capabilities. To support *only* `Tls12`, you'd use:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Answer (score 1):

.NET 4.6.2 should use TLS 1.2 by default. The code you have should not be needed at all.
My guess is you might be having a different `httpRuntime` version which causes the problem.

Try removing the code from your `Global.asax` and explicitly set the `httpRuntime` version in your `web.config`:

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.2" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: I had set the project to 4.6.2 but the web.config said 4.5.1

Comment: I changed the web.config to 4.6.2 AND set the security protol to Tls12 in global.asax but I still get the same error in firefox

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, the problem was IIS express.  Running the site locally and opening up the console window gave me the TLS error message, but When I ran the site deployed up in Azure I no longer received the error message so It must have been because I was running it locally through IIS express

Comment: Yes, you have to ensure where the site is hosted has TLS 1.2 enabled. Even if the calling application communicates over TLS 1.2, the machine it's communicating with may not have TLS 1.2 enabled which could result in failed handshake